# How to find p-value from Johansen test in R (urca::ca.jo)?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

Using the `urca` package in R, and the `ca.jo()` function, I can run a Johansen test and get the test statistic and critical values of the test. However, the function does not return p-value(s). I was wondering how to manually find the p-value given the results from the `ca.jo()` function, or if there was another package which calculates it in the first place.